# How to convert map[string]*structpb.ListValue to map[string][]string

Tags: go, types

Suppose I have these two Go variables `x` & `y`:

```
var y map[string]*structpb.ListValue
var x map[string][]string
```

How can I put the data of y in x? Can I cast it?

Comment: You must copy the data from to `y` to `x` using a couple of nested loops.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I cast it?

No.

```
y := map[string]*structpb.ListValue{
    "a": {Values: []*structpb.Value{
        {Kind: &structpb.Value_StringValue{StringValue: "value"}}}},
}

x := *(*map[string][]string)(unsafe.Pointer(&y)) // map[a:[]]
```

You have to convert `*structpb.ListValue` to `[]string` manually

```
for key, value := range y {
    var s []string
    s = append(s, toSlice(value)...)
    x[key] = s
}
```

```
func toSlice(val *structpb.ListValue) []string {
 //mapping
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Heading MuffinTop's advice, this is the solution I implemented:

```
x = make(map[string][]string)
var convertedList []string
for key, mapValue := range y {
    convertedList = make([]string, 0)
    for _, listElement := range mapValue.Values {
        convertedList = append(convertedList, listElement.String())
    }
    x[key] = convertedTL
}
```